# RequestMapping leads to 404 Error

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to call a delete method from my jsp. It should map to the delete method in my controller. That's my code:
In JSP:

```
<td><a href="deleteEntry/${product.name}">Delete Entry</a></td>
```

In Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/productbook")
public class ProductController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEntry/{name}")
public ModelAndView deleteEntry(@PathVariable String name){
    System.out.println("I'm HERE");
    .
            ... some code

}
```

I always get a 404 error when clicking my delete link. Any idea why?

Additionally, I get a warning for every time I click the delete link: 
e.g. WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI XY in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

my web.xml

```
 <web-app>
 <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

 <servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Additionally, I noticed when I click the delete link that the filename "SpringMVC" is missing in the URL:

localhost:8080/productbook/deleteEntry/namenamename

my mvc-servlet xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.controller.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean class="mypackage.validator.GuestbookValidator" />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

 </beans>
```

Comment: `localhost:8080/productbook/deleteEntry/namenamename` is not the same as your mapping. If its a typo, please fix it. And if you have problem with generating the correct URL, then we will need to see more of the JSP generating it.

Comment: now I'm confused :S. What would be the correct mapping?

Comment: You have `/deleteEntry` in your example URL, but `/delete` in your `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Comment: it was a typo. In my code I used it without the typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, finally! Added two ** to both the mapping of the class and method. Now the error is gone, and my Sysout was called :)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/productbook/**")
public class ProductController { 

@RequestMapping(value="**/deleteEntry/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView deleteEntry(@PathVariable String name) {
    System.out.println("I'm here!");
    SOME CODE
    SOME CODE
    SOME CODE

    return model;

}
```

my link:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/productbook/deleteEntry/${product.name}" />">Delete Entry</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dollar sign from your mapping definition:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/deleteEntry/{name}")
```

And always generate URLs in a proper way:

```
<c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/productbook/deleteEntry/${product.name}" />
<td><a href="${deleteUrl}">Delete Entry</a></td>
```

Comment: I did but it didn't change the 404 :(

Comment: Updated my answer also with information how the target URL should be generated. By the way, I assume you are using <mvc:annotation-driven />... correct?

Answer (score 0):

you need to add productbook and servlet mapping as prefix:

```
<td><a href="/{servlet-mapping}/productbook/delete/${product.name}">Delete Entry</a></td>
```

so for example - if you mapped the dispatcher servlet to "/api" (and you have a api-servlet.xml file under the WEB-INF folder) then the link should be:

```
<td><a href="/api/productbook/delete/${product.name}">Delete Entry</a></td>
```

unless you're using some kind of TLD that saves you from doing this...

Comment: In my case, the url - pattern was simply "/". I changed the link to <td><a href="/productbook/delete/${product.name}">Delete Entry</a></td> and it also didn't help :(

Comment: when you examine the html, you get a real name instead of ${product.name}?

Comment: You mean in the link? Yes it gets substituted by the product name.

Comment: i just noticed that you're missing the method: @RequestMapping(value = "/delete/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)