# Request Mapping returns 404 instead of the mapped String after creating a basic example from spring.start.io

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I've already been on the following topics but **none** seemed to worked for me:

1. [RequestMapping leads to 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002543/requestmapping-leads-to-404-error) , added the regex ( `/app/**` to **Rest Controller** and `**/api` to the **Method**) but still won't map it.
2. [Spring @RequestMapping, 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41678768/spring-requestmapping-404-error) , added `<packaging>jar</packaging>`   to my **pom.xml** , although i can't find the path to change it (i doubt that the issue might be there, i'm not sure though).
3. [Request Mapping returning error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36863440/request-mapping-returning-error-404) , i visit the correct **endpoint** which is `localhost:8080/api` (port is not in use), i also tried it with another port number.
4. [Spring RequestMapping 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43535279/spring-requestmapping-404-error) , we might have the same issue here, i don't see why i should change the mapping, haven't changed anything on default directories or files.

This is **not** the first time i'm making a **Springboot** application

- My `pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>myrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>remoteapi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>remoteapi</name>
    <description>Rest Mobile Dev ICSD Api</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- My `RestController` class

```java
package Controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MainController {

    
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/api")
    public String test()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

This is my **directory**, the `MainController` class is inside `Controller` package

[image]

The `URL` i'm accessing it from is `localhost:8080/api`

**Important Note:** if i run the exact method with the exact mapping on **an older project**, **it runs perfectly**.

My Comments: This is pretty odd , since i've never changed anything on configurations, probably i missed something when i created the project? I Still haven't figured what that might be.

Edit: Added the directory, and the that location i'm trying to access it

Comment: In which package is your main class located? And what is the URL you're using to reach this controller?

Comment: the class is located at `Controller` package and i'm trying to access it at `localhost:8080/api` , i'm updating the questing with this information

Comment: So package name is **not** Controller. It's myrest. That's what the problem is. All Spring beans must be in the same package as, or in a subpackage of, the main application class. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-locating-the-main-class

Comment: In another project of mine, i have in the same directory `src/main/java` two packages, one of them contains the controller, and another package in the same dir that has the @SpringBootApplication main class, although the **package name** of the controller is named as a **sub** package of the main class. So basically if i rename `Controller` to `myrest.Controller` it should work right?

Comment: @JBNizet i renamed it to `myrest.Controller` and it worked!

Comment: Yes, as I just explained, and as the application I linked to explains. You should really stick to Java naming conventions, too. Packages should start with your reverse domain name (com.mycompany.myproject...), and should be lowercase. The more you disrespect conventions, the more bugs or difficulties you'll face.

Comment: @JBNizet indeed, i will change it to lowercase. Thank you , you may post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I renamed the `Controller` package to `myrest.controller` ,

has to be a subpackage of the main package!

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, SpringBoot only scan packages which have the same prefix with Application class (in your case: myrest).
If you want spring boot scan another package, you should define them through annotation: `@ComponentScan("package.hear")`